# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' with nHibernate in NUnit

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, nunit

I've installed `FluentNHibernate` and `System.Data.SQLite.MSIL` with Nuget.

I wrote some unit tests and tried to execute them. But my test setup is failing miserably:

> Probel.NDoctor.Statistics.UnitTests.SQLite.ChartQueryTest (TestFixtureSetUp):
>   SetUp : FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException : An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>     ----> System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Well, Nuget didn't import `SQLite.Interop.dll` when I installed the package `System.Data.SQLite.MSIL`...

I'm using:

- `NHibernate 3.3.1.4000` (installed when I installed `FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.733`)
- `System.Data.SQLite.MSIL`
- `NUnit 2.6.2.12296`
- Visual Studio 2010

Note all these dll import was dont via Nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'SQLite.Interop.dll' is contained in the `System.Data.SQLite` Nuget package. The `System.Data.SQLite.MSIL` package you installed only contains the ADO.NET provider. Just uninstall `System.Data.SQLite.MSIL` and install `System.Data.SQLite` which has the ADO.NET provider and the unmanaged library. That should fix your issue.